# In PostgreSQL, calculate the average duration (interval of time) that an ID appears in a single Date column

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-manipulation

**Background**

I'm pretty new to SQL and to Postgres. I'm trying to get some basic descriptions of some data in a large table about car and motorcycle insurance claims -- call the table `claims`. The data have ~15 columns, but only 2 are relevant here:

```
     id        | claim_date   |
---------------+--------------|
 001           |  2011-01-30  |
 001           |  2012-04-12  |
 001           |  2014-06-27  |
 002           |  2017-09-03  |
 002           |  2018-12-25  |
```

**The Problem**

I'd like to know the average interval of time that `ID`s appear in this dataset. Were I to do this by hand, I'd subtract the earliest from the latest `claim_date` for each `ID`, sum them, and divide by the number of distinct `ID`s (2, in this case). This'd give me a result of `861` days here.

The main issue is that I'm not really sure how to write this out in query form in Postgres.

**What I've Tried**

In similar posts, other users have asked about subtracting the date in one `date` column from another to get a date interval, but that's not exactly what I'm after.

I've tried a query like this:

```
select max(claims.claim_date) - min(claims.claim_date) date_diff
from claims
group by ID
```

But only gets me part way, just a list of `max`-`min` intervals for each `ID`. I've also tried using `AVG` like so:

```
select AVG(max(claims.claim_date) - min(claims.claim_date))
from claims
group by ID
```

But here I get the error `ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two levels of aggregation.

```
SELECT avg(d) AS ad
       FROM (SELECT max(claim_date)
                    - min(claim_date) AS d
                    FROM claims
                    GROUP BY id) AS x;
```

Comment: And if I wanted to do the very same thing, just on a subset of `id`? For instance, only on those `ID` whose value of `column_x` = 1? (`column_x` here being an INT variable with only 1 or 0 in each cell.)

Comment: @logjammin: Then use a `WHERE` clause in the inner query to filter for such records.